# Records inside a geo polygon with Searchkick or Rails + ElasticSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to find a way to get elasticsearch to return records contained inside a polygon - either by using searchkick (preferable) or by using elastic search + ruby directly.

I see that searchkick can handle returning records near to a point or inside a box, but I can't see how to construct the query for records inside a polygon. Any direction much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Might help someone.

In a model named `Vendor` with a polygon property named `delivery_area` you can do something like following.

```
Vendor.search('*', where: {
      delivery_area: {
        geo_shape: {
          type: 'point',
          relation: 'intersects',
          coordinates: [params[:lng], params[:lat]]
        }
      }
    })
```